# How to fix the error "Unable to open debugger port " in Android Studio?

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio, adb

```
Error running Android Debugger (8600):
    Unable to open debugger port (localhost:8600):
    java.net.SocketException "Connection reset"
```

Comment: This problem seems to stem from multiple causes.  Accepted the answer that fixes the most common scenario.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I was able to fix this with these commands:

- `adb kill-server`
- `adb start-server`

Comment: This did it for me!

Comment: This problem seems to stem from multiple causes.  Accepted the answer that fixes the most common scenario.

Comment: I just did the kill-server, android studio auto-started it after a couple of seconds

Answer (score 39):

Try Restarting ANDROID STUDIO (Worked for me)

Comment: Good Ol' restart. Thanks

Comment: Worked for me too

Comment: Worked for me too, Android Studio 3.2

Answer (score 6):

In my case, there was another service running on my laptop(Windows) that was using the port 8600.  I opened Task Manager and stopped the service.  Now, I could debug my application normally without the above error.

Answer (score 6):

I solve the problem by checking my localhost.

Making sure `127.0.0.1  localhost`.

Answer (score 2):

For me this problem started when i upgraded my Android Studio to new version.

Please go to options menu **Build** and choose **Clean Project**.

[image]

That is it project started to run again and error was gone.

Answer (score 1):

I tried other answers (e.g. restarting Android Studio) but they didn't solve this for me.

I had accidentally selected MTP (Media Transfer Protocol) in my Developer Options/USB Configuration. It started working once I set it to PTP (Picture Transfer Protocol).

**EDIT:** On reflection it's probably just that I changed the protocol because I've had the same issue since while on PTP. Hence I'm suggesting that the real answer is to change the protocol on the phone and, if you might need it, don't forget to change it back.

Answer (score 1):

It could be that you need to wait for your code to stop compiling before you attached the debugger. I had a similar error and all I needed was patience.

Answer (score 0):

If you using WiFi debug:

1. Exit ANDROID STUDIO
2. adb kill-server && adb start-server
3. adb tcpip 5555
4. adb connect [your wi-fi IP]:5555
5. Start ANDROID STUDIO

Answer (score 0):

I did spent quite an amount of time by trying below things:

- Re-installing old(3.6.3) and new(4.0.1) Android studio and Android SDK's
- checking all the security things in newly installed Mac OS Catalina
- Checking all the developer options in my physical android device and AVD
- And all the things mentioned in this post as well: https://medium.com/returntrue/android-studio-cant-bind-to-local-8600-for-debugger-%E3%81%A7%E3%83%87%E3%83%90%E3%83%83%E3%82%AC%E3%83%BC%E3%81%8C%E6%B0%B8%E4%B9%85%E3%81%AB%E8%B5%B7%E5%8B%95%E3%81%97%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%E3%81%A8%E3%81%8D%E3%81%AB%E3%82%84%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F%E3%81%93%E3%81%A8-8f5dd9c8ca70

Finally a small change in my `/etc/host` file resolved this issue. I commented from `0.0.0.0` and `::1` for `localhost` local DNS entries and enabled only `127.0.0.1`

[image]