# Android Studio 3.0 can't debug

Tags: android, android-studio

My Android Studio version is beta6.

error message:

[image]

I have tried restart android studio and adb, and reboot my computer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.net.SocketException: Connection reset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62929/java-net-socketexception-connection-reset)

Comment: Something might be using that port. Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41305611/change-android-studio-debug-port to change your port number to something more obselete

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32381180/how-to-fix-the-error-unable-to-open-debugger-port-in-android-studio The port at 8603 might be used by other service