# Android Studio - Unable to open debugger port: java.io.IOException

Tags: android, android-studio

I am stuck in a problem here.

I cannot attach debug using Android Studio 3.5.1.

Its keeping showing me the message "Error running 'Android Debugger (8600)': Unable to open debugger port (localhost:8600): java.io.IOException"

I tried a lot of things like:

```
adb reset
invalidate
restart windows
reinstall android studio
```

and none of them works.

And I cannot find Enable ADB Integration on this version.

Anyone knows how to fix it?

**EDIT**

Debugging with emulator is working with all versions.

Debugging with devices is working only with devices with Android 9.0+

Kill and start adb didn't work. 
I dont think its a local problem because its happen with a lot of people here. Its seems to be a project problem

Comment: Having the same issue here.  Checked hosts file, checked multiple versions of adb.  still having same issue.

Comment: Nothing yet....

Comment: Probably duplicated. Did you tried this answers -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32381180/how-to-fix-the-error-unable-to-open-debugger-port-in-android-studio

Comment: yes @devzeze. I said it in my question

Comment: are you using emulator or physical device?

Comment: Using a physical device

Comment: its happening in emulator too

Comment: https://www.guru99.com/adb-connect.html

Comment: Also, make sure the USB cable that you are using is capable of transferring data!

Answer (score 5):

You might check this 3 things: 
1.
Youre not running a not debuggable version.
android:debuggable="false" in Android Manifest

2.
In Android studio you re not building a release version
Check in Build variants in bottom left corner.

3.
If nothing works use Troubleshoot device connections
Tools -> Connection Assistant
or older version
Tools -> Troubleshoot device connections

And try out the helper page from google (seems for older versions)
https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device#assistant

Comment: didnt find Troubleshoot device connections in A.S 3.3

Comment: New location is in Tools -> Connection Assistant

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
adb usb
```

For `linux`, e.g., `ubuntu`: start all commands with `sudo` like this:
`sudo adb kill-server`.

Answer (score 0):

its your connection issue, cant find your device DNS.

what is your OS ?

In windows:

> you must go to network and find duplicate dns and clear it (Search for
>   it)

In mac:

> you must kill adb or delete that and run a new version

last hit is Update emulator in sdk

Answer (score 0):

- .First you need to check your build.gradle(app) file , and ensure that your build is debuggable.
- .If debuggable then you need to check adb is working or not in your system, you can 
  check by just press 'adb' .

  - if its working then check devices by 'adb devices', it will show all connected devices.
  - add kill-server  then enter and adb start-server

Answer (score -1):

Try this. I have had luck with this approach when I run into problems with adb.

You can check if the device is recognised or not using

```
adb devices
```

If it is indeed recognised you may try to kill adb and start it again

```
add kill-server
adb start-server
```